# Forbidden access to a image in database

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I'm sending to an app the location of an image: `http:\/\/192.168.0.193\/Symfony\/src\/OBCarsTest2Bundle\/Resources\/public\/images\/cars\/car2.jpg`

her is the json object i am sending:

```
{"carInfo":
    {"name":"Mercedes",
     "model":"CLA-Class",
     "carvin":"ffgf",
     "price":"5556",
     "currency":"L.L",
     "id":2,
     "path":"http:\/\/192.168.0.193\/Symfony\/src\/OBCarsTest2Bundle\/Resources\/public\/images\/cars\/car2.jpg"}
}
```

but it gets an error :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /Symfony/src/OBCarsTest2Bundle/Resources/public/images/cars/car2.jpg
`on this server.`    
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 192.168.0.193 Port 80
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

For more details i am using `symfony` framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please store the image in  `web` folder not inside the  `bundle` ..

Comment: you should use this command to store assets from bundle to web directory php app/console assets:install web or use --symlink option with command to avoid copying hardcopies